# Excluding the base system process from running applications

Tags: android

I got a list of running applications by using `Activity Manager`.

I filtered that Application list by `RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` .

Now the problem is, I need to exclude the base system process from that List.

Is there any way or any method in the Activity Manager class?

Comment: What do you consider "the base system process" to be?

Comment: @CommonsWare  I need to show what are Application Which User download and installed in device